# How do I conduct Presale off chain? Keeping the address and the amount of coins purchased

Tags: solidity, erc-20, ether, addresses, mapping

I'm creating a presale website and a presale coin in solidity. How do I keep tract of the poeple who bought it something like whitelisting right

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.